# Two Bootstrap accordions on same page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am using Boostrap framework, but I have problem with accordions. When I am trying to add 2 bootstrap accordions http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse on the same page so only one works fine. Does someone how to add 2 these accordions on the same page?

Thx for your time.

Comment: Here is my accordion.js https://gist.github.com/2552147
and here is my HTML https://gist.github.com/2552152

Comment: @user13746 how are you calling your acordions? try to post your full markup, if you can post it on a http://jsfiddle.net it would make it easier to answer.

Comment: I call my accordions in otherjs.js https://gist.github.com/2553297

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your second accordion is not working because you are referencing the first accordion on the `data-parent` and accordion object ids (e.g. `id="collapseTwo"`), once you differentiate both accordions and set the proper `data-parent` property on the second accordion everything works fine.

**Fixed markup with unique ids and proper data-parent references**

```
<h1>First Accordion</h1>
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body in collapse" style="height: auto; ">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<h1>Second Accordion</h1>
<div class="accordion2" id="accordion3">
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapse4">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse4" class="accordion-body in collapse" style="height: auto; ">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapse5">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse5" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
      <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapse6">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse6" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/STqCF/

Answer (score 1):

First all of you have to keep in mind that in javascript and jquery every id will must be unique and used only one time in one page. It is the only cause for the problem is that your ids conflict in the page.
So you have to correct two things,
data-parent of an anchor and href of an anchor

A demo for you

```
<div class="accordion_one">
<!--starting accourdion one-->
<h2 class="adelfox_heading">Accourdion Style 1</h2>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#1_collapseOne">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
              Our Solution
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="1_collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#1_collapseTwo">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                Our Technology
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="1_collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#1_collapseThree">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                Our Mission
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="1_collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#1_collapseFour">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                Our Vision
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="1_collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
<!--end of starting accourdion one-->
</div>



<div class="accordion_two">
<!--starting accourdion two-->
<h2 class="adelfox_heading">Accourdion Style 2</h2>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#2_collapseOne">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
              Our Solution
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="2_collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#2_collapseTwo">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                Our Technology
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="2_collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#2_collapseThree">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                Our Mission
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="2_collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#2_collapseFour">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                Our Vision
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="2_collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
<!--end of starting accourdion two-->
</div>
```

Comment: I was using duplicate accordions on the same page and it's exactly as Andres and Spondon said. I added arbitrary text to differentiate my ID's and it worked. Good work fellas!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Update the **views-bootstrap-accordion-plugin-style.tpl.php** in order to have a unique id to this:

```
<div id="views-bootstrap-accordion-<?php print $id ?>" class="<?php print $classes ?>">
  <?php foreach ($rows as $key => $row): ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle"
             data-toggle="collapse"
             data-parent="#views-bootstrap-accordion-<?php print $id ?>"
             href="#collapse<?php print $id . "-" . $key ?>">
            <?php print $titles[$key] ?>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>

      <div id="collapse<?php print $id . "-" . $key ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <?php print $row ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```