# Two dynamically generated bootstrap accordions conflicting with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Working in Angular here, the application has the ability to open multiple "panes" within one browser tab.  These panes essentially function like their own browser tab.  I've got a bootstrap accordion, using the standard sort of bootstrap setup:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionOne"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                 <div class="">CONTENT</div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionTwo"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                 <div class="">CONTENT 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Issue here is that because of the multiple panes, there is the potential that a user could open 2 panes to the same area and render this accordion twice.  Doing so means that clicking any element on the second rendered accordion will only control the first accordion.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfakey/9jur11sh/1/) for example

Since I have no idea how many times the user could generate this "pane" at once, is there a good approach for tackling this sort of thing?

Note:  I know why this is happening, with the data-targets and all.  This is a question on how to solve that dynamically.

[Tangentially related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373723/two-bootstrap-accordions-on-same-page)

Answer (score 1):

They should have unique ID attributes. Change the 2nd to `accordion2` or some other unique identifier. All of the panels must have unique ID's too. If they're dynamically generated, that logic must change to generate unique id's instead of using the same id over again with each iteration.

http://www.bootply.com/85EJ8o0bWu

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionOne">Section One</a>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="">CONTENT</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionTwo">Section 2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="">CONTENT 2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionThree">Section 3</a>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="">CONTENT 3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#accordionOne2">Section One</a>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="">CONTENT</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#accordionTwo2">Section 2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionTwo2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="">CONTENT 2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#accordionThree2">Section 3</a>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionThree2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="">CONTENT 3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If you're specifically looking to understand **iteration in Angular**, it really depends on how the data is structured, and there are many different approaches with ng-repeat.

[Repeating Bootstrap accordions with Angular](http://www.codeply.com/go/OzGLHWHisL).

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `data-target` must be identic as the accordion body `id`.

See the example:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordionTwo" data-parent="#accordion"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="accordionTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
             <div class="">CONTENT 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div
```