# How can I make the accordions on a webpage act independently from each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have two accordions that live in different sections on a webpage through an CMS. I have updated the ids and the data-parent to differentiate them, but I'm still having issues and noticed the following:

- When I upload the webpage, the first headings on both accordions open with the (-) symbol. When I close the tab, it doesn't go to (+) like it should. This problem happens on all the tabs.
- I also noticed that when I click on "expand all" or "collapse all" on either the first or second accordion, the other one also does the same thing at the same time.

First accordion:

```
<!-- Expand/ Collapse Buttons-->
<p class="button-container">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-expand-all" id="openAll-faq">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&#160;Expand All 
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-collapse-all" id="closeAll-faq">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>&#160;Collapse All 
    </button>
</p>
<!-- Collapsible Steps Section -->
<div aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
    <!-- First Collapsible Item-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="step-wrapper" id="headingOne" role="tab">
            <div class="step-description">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a aria-controls="collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button">
                        <span style="font-size: 32px; font-family: League Gothic;">Heading 1</span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="step-button anchorLink">
                <a aria-controls="collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus step-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div aria-labelledby="headingOne" class="panel-collapse collapse faq-a in" id="collapseOne" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Copy goes here&#160;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Second Collapsible Item-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="step-wrapper" id="headingTwo" role="tab">
            <!--<div class="step-number"><span class="step-number-font">2</span></div> -->
            <div class="step-description">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a aria-controls="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" role="button">
                        <span style="font-size: 32px; font-family: League Gothic;">Heading 2</span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="step-button anchorLink">
                <a aria-controls="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" role="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus step-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div aria-labelledby="headingTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse faq-a" id="collapseTwo" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Copy goes here&#160;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Third Collapsible Item-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="step-wrapper" id="headingThree" role="tab">
            <!-- <div class="step-number"><span class="step-number-font">3</span></div> -->
            <div class="step-description">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a aria-controls="collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" role="button">
                        <span style="font-size: 32px; font-family: League Gothic;">Heading 3</span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="step-button anchorLink">
                <a aria-controls="collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" role="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus step-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div aria-labelledby="headingThree" class="panel-collapse collapse faq-a" id="collapseThree" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>copy goes here&#160;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fourth Collapsible Item-->
</div>
<style>
    <!--
#self-report:before {
        display:none;
    }
-->
</style>
```

Second accordion:

```
<!-- Expand/ Collapse Buttons-->
<p class="button-container">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-expand-all" id="openAll-faq2">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&#160;Expand All 
    
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-collapse-all" id="closeAll-faq2">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>&#160;Collapse All 
    
    </button>
</p>
<!-- Collapsible Steps Section -->
<div aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist">
    <!-- First Collapsible Item-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="step-wrapper" id="headingOne2" role="tab">
            <div class="step-description">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a aria-controls="collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" data-parent="#accordion2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne2" role="button">
                        <span style="font-size: 32px; font-family: League Gothic;">Heading 4</span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="step-button anchorLink">
                <a aria-controls="collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne2" role="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus step-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div aria-labelledby="headingOne" class="panel-collapse collapse faq-a in" id="collapseOne2" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">Body copy here&#160;
                
                <br />
                <p>&#160;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Second Collapsible Item-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="step-wrapper" id="headingTwo2" role="tab">
            <!--<div class="step-number"><span class="step-number-font">2</span></div> -->
            <div class="step-description">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a aria-controls="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo2" role="button">
                        <span style="font-size: 32px; font-family: League Gothic;">Heading 5</span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="step-button anchorLink">
                <a aria-controls="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo2" role="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus step-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div aria-labelledby="headingTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse faq-a" id="collapseTwo2" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">Body copy here&#160;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Third Collapsible Item-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="step-wrapper" id="headingThree2" role="tab">
            <!-- <div class="step-number"><span class="step-number-font">3</span></div> -->
            <div class="step-description">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a aria-controls="collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree2" role="button">
                        <span style="font-size: 32px; font-family: League Gothic;">Heading 6</span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="step-button anchorLink">
                <a aria-controls="collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree2" role="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus step-icon"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div aria-labelledby="headingThree" class="panel-collapse collapse faq-a" id="collapseThree2" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Body copy here&#160;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fourth Collapsible Item-->
</div>
<style>
    <!--
#self-report:before {
        display:none;
    }
-->
</style>
```

JS file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.anchorLink').click(function() {
        $(this).find("span.glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-minus glyphicon-plus");
    });
    $('#openAll-faq').click(function() {
        $('.anchorLink .glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
        $('.collapse.faq-a').collapse('show');
    });
    $('#closeAll-faq').click(function() {
        $('.anchorLink .glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
        $('.collapse.faq-a').collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

Second JS file, not sure about this set up

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.anchorLink').click(function() {
        $(this).find("span.glyphicon").toggleClass("glyphicon-minus glyphicon-plus");
    });
    $('#openAll-faq2').click(function() {
        $('.anchorLink .glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
        $('.collapse.faq-a').collapse('show');
    });
    $('#closeAll-faq2').click(function() {
        $('.anchorLink .glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
        $('.collapse.faq-a').collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

What else can I do to eliminate this dependency and have both accordions co-exist on the webpage?

Thanks.

I updated the IDs and the data-parent based on this: [Two Bootstrap accordions on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373723/two-bootstrap-accordions-on-same-page). I was able to get the tabs on open on the second accordion after that.

But I also noticed other problems, like the "collapse all" and "expand all" not working on the second accordion., so I made a second JS file with a unique # at the beginning.

I expected each accordion to act as its own entity and the (-) to appear when the content shows and the (+) to appear when the content is closed.

I'm still experiencing problems.

Comment: Use more specific selectors

Comment: please explain "I'm still experiencing problems."

Comment: @FarhanIbnWahid 
When I wrote that, I was referring to the two bullet points at the beginning. Even after changing the IDs, the data-parent, and creating a second JS with a different #, the accordions are not working correctly.

Comment: @BeeC update these comments in your question